# JS: If statement to check if var exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have a AngularJS app where I have an array defined that has a group of dealers. Something like this:

```
     $scope.dealers = [{
            name: "Dealer Name",
            address: "Address goes here",
            website:"site.com",
            lat: "latitude",
            lng: "longitude"
            territory: ['County1', 'County2', 'County3']
          },
          {
            name: "Dealer Name",
            address: "Address goes here",
            website:"site.com",
            lat: "latitude",
            lng: "longitude",
            territory: ['County1', 'County2', 'County3']
              }, 
    ];
```

A user will input their zip code, and then using the Google Geocode API, I convert their zip code to lat/long coordinates and find their closest dealer based off of coordinates between them, and all of the dealers.

That is working fine.

Here is where I need help. Each dealer has a territory (in the array as counties) that needs to be checked first, before finding the closest dealer, because some dealers have counties in their territories that are actually geographically closer to another dealer.

I have a var that stores the users County based on their zip. So I need to make an IF statement that checks the userZip variable against the dealers array to see if that county exists anywhere in the array. If it does, then I need to return the name of that dealer. If it does not, I will have an ELSE statement that just runs the function I already have, which will just find the closest dealer to their location.

Comment: Array.some, Array.indexOf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
let dealers = [{
    name: "Dealer Name",
    address: "Address goes here",
    website: "site.com",
    lat: "latitude",
    lng: "longitude",
    territory: ['County1', 'County2', 'County3']
  },
  {
    name: "Dealer Name",
    address: "Address goes here",
    website: "site.com",
    lat: "latitude",
    lng: "longitude",
    territory: ['County1', 'County2', 'County3']
  },
];

let country = 'County2';
let found = dealers.find(d => d.territory.includes(country));

if(found)
  console.log(found);
else
  console.log("..find closest...");


//another case
country = 'NotAnywhere';
found = dealers.find(d => d.territory.includes(country));

if(found)
  console.log(found);
else
  console.log("..find closest...");
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I try this:

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.territory.includes')